# How does one right-justify bootstrap pills with css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header with three sections, left, middle and right.  I cant seem to come up with the proper css to make the column on the right (with 'email history' and 'back to list') float to the right side of the column. How can anyone tell me how this is done?  Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="col-sm-5" style="text-align:left">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg navbar-btn">Save Contact</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align:center">
   <h2 class="branding">Edit Contact</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="active"><a href="/GoHistory">Email History</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="/email_marketing/contact-list">Back To List</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**NOTE:**  The answer below is valid for Bootstrap 2 and 3; in Bootstrap 4 the equivalent class is `float-right`, and [viewport-specific float classes are also available.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)

---

The easiest option is to add the class `pull-right` to the `ul` element. This will float the pills to the right.

Sidenote: you can replace those inline styles with the helper classes `text-left` (which is often redundant) and `text-center`.

Here's a bootply example: http://www.bootply.com/134139

Comment: This will cause some float issues though, and in my experience, .clearfix doesn't help it get cleared.

Comment: On the one hand, I feel so stupid when the fix is so easy. On the other hand, it is nice when the fix is soooo easy. Thank You.

Comment: Just a warning, if you aren't using columns, and just a plain nav, you'll need my solution below :) And yes, glad it was easy :P

Comment: The `pull-right` utility has been [removed](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities) in favor of `float-right`, so the answer should be updated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; I've updated the answer to address both the old & new versions.

Answer (score 3):

Need to overwrite some Bootstrap styling...

You'll need to remove the float on the list items and set it to display:inline-block. Then for the unordered-list element, add text-align:left.

Here's the CSS:

```
ul.nav.nav-pills {
    text-align: right;
}

.nav-pills>li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This method is best for the right alignment of bootstrap nav-tabs. Here is a sample for bootstrap nav-tabs with above CSS.http://jsbin.com/yuxiyi/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score -1):

Try a `style="float:left;"` on each div. And a `<ul class="nav nav-pills" style="float:right;">`. After that clear the float.